# Windows Security deletes my USB virus as soon as I plug it in

Tags: malware, antivirus, antimalware, usb

I am studying ethical hacking and I work in the cybersecurity department of a company.

I have been testing a hacking program but some PCs delete this executable as soon as I plug in the USB and some don't.

I have been trying some things but I can't get anything without an external antivirus.

My questions are:

- How can I force Windows to detect this and delete the suspicious executables?
- How could I bypass this measure and execute my program?

Comment: I'm worried that some PCs do not delete it. What is different about those PCs?

Comment: The term you are looking for is "AV evasion". There are quite a lot of tools to help with this.

Comment: @schroeder thanks, that helps me a lot, I didn't know how to search for this kind of information

Answer (score -2):

I'm not sure if there is a way to force Windows Defender to do this exactly. But you can change the settings in the registry to stop all autoplaying of files from USB devices which is a good start.

There are a number of common ways of bypassing this, one way is to pack/crypt/obfuscate the exe/bat so the AV won't recognize it. AV evasion is a complicated topic but a simple example is: Anti virus detects malware by scanning the file for known code/string snippets. So you may have a batch script that contains the string `C:\Windows\System32` which gets flagged so you can encrypt that string in the script and then decrypt it at run time.

Another way I have seen is by using malicious USB tools like rubber ducky. Where basically the computer will recognize the device as a keyboard so someone can program it to open powershell and download and run a malicious file by simulating key presses.

Comment: Auto-play and rubber ducky are completely irrelevant to the question. This answer would be greatly improved if you cut those parts and expanded on the AV evasion techniques you mentioned.

Comment: Please respond to comments in the comment field. Please do not editorialise in posts.

Comment: Auto-play has absolutely nothing with Defender or AV. Scans are performed when the media is mounted, not when files are executed. And rubber ducky devices either need to be purchased specifically, or, if you have more comfort, you can reprogram a microcontroller. Neither options are relevant to what was asked.

Comment: This is why I said "which is a good start", I meant it's good practise. Regarding your second point I'm not sure if that's strictly correct. I think most AV these days will scan process memory whilst it's running but I could be wrong. https://www.microsoft.com/security/blog/2018/09/27/out-of-sight-but-not-invisible-defeating-fileless-malware-with-behavior-monitoring-amsi-and-next-gen-av/